# Sanitize input being logged by third party frameworks like Spring

Tags: validation, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, esapi, veracode

We are using third party jars like Spring Cloud Eureka in our application.

We recently did a  Veracode testing and found there are a lot of issues identified with eureka and ribbon client jars which were part of Spring cloud Eureka.

Most of these issues were,
Improper Output Neutralization for Logs (CWE ID 117)

I understand what CWE ID 117 is. We need to sanitize untrusted data before logging them.

But ,my question is, since it is third party library and not part of the application I cannot fix them.

Is there a way to fix it with minimal effort using any Configuration /Aspects/Interceptor rather than changing every such class with the issue in the third party library.

I feel this will take more time and also need spring cloud team help on it, which I may not be able to get at short time.

Can someone help me on the way to approach this issue. Otherwise , we may not be able to use the third party jars in my application, which becomes a concern beacuse a huge effort ha sbeen spent already using the third party libraries.

Comment: You can probably do a catch-all by modifying the logback file appender to strip/encode characters that could be used to try to hack browser-based log viewers. The code scanner is likely too dumb to know that you've done this (I hate them with a passion) so you'll have to manually highlight your work to your powers that be.

Comment: If I understand, you're worried about lower-level logging from the spring framework?  Have you identified whether or not user-input is being displayed in those logging messages?